# Using python's mock to temporarily delete an object from a dict

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-mock

I am writing a test for some code that checks for a value in `os.environ` (I know this isn't optimal, but I have to go with it).  I would like to remove an entry from os.environ for the duration of the test.  I am not sure if mock supports this.  I know `patch.dict` can be used to modify an item, but I want the key/value pair removed.  I would like something along these lines:

```
print os.environ
{ ... , 'MY_THING': 'foo', ... }

with mock.patch.dict.delete('os.environ', 'MY_THING'):
    # run the test
    # ( 'MY_THING' in os.environ ) should return False

# everything back to normal now    
print os.environ
{ ... , 'MY_THING': 'foo', ... }
```

Is there a way to perform such a feat?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) doesn't quite work like your sample desired code. `patch.dict` is a function which requires an argument. You probably want to use it like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> import mock
>>> with mock.patch.dict('os.environ'):
...     del os.environ['PATH']
...     print 'PATH' in os.environ
...
False
>>> print 'PATH' in os.environ
True
```

Comment: mock.patch.dict doesn't work like that, because I made it up :)  Your solution works for me though.

Answer (score 2):

For deleting the item, you can simply use:

```
my_thing = os.environ['MY_THING']  # Gotta store it to restore it later
del os.environ['MY_THING']
```

And then restore it with:

```
os.environ['MY_THING'] = my_thing
```

Comment: That seems not very stable.  If the test fails halfway through, I'm stuck with MY_THING deleted from os.environ :(

Comment: Or use `my_thing = os.environ.pop('MY_THING')` and omit the `del`.

Comment: If you want it in a form that works with `with`, create a class `DictDelete` with a method `__enter__` that does the deletion, and `__exit__` that does the restore. Then use `with DictDelete()`. I'd format it nicely, but comments are limited.

Comment: this can break other test

Answer (score 0):

For those using Pytest, note that the answers involving context-managers do not work. Instead, Pytest provides a built-in fixture for Mocker, which automatically assumes a context-manager roll:

```py
import os

def test_before_change():
    print('before change: ' + os.environ['PATH'])

def test_env_change(mocker):
    mock.patch.dict(os.environ)
    del os.environ['PATH']
    print('PATH would go here...if I had one! ' + os.environ['PATH']) 


def test_before_change():
    print('after change: ' + os.environ['PATH'])


# now run the pytest
```